# How to convert date time string to current timezone

Tags: php

As an example, I have a string containing the following:

```
2012-06-18T11:45:00Z
```

I want to display it in the timezone I am currently in.

So the output (depending on format) would be something like:

```
2012-06-18 12:45:00
```

as I am in BST at the moment, but in the winter (when I'm in GMT) I want the output to be like:

```
2012-06-18 11:45:00
```

Can I get some PHP (version 7.0) that will do this

Comment: The PHP date objects (http://php.net/datetime) allow you to modify the timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following;
(Choose the timezone you would like to display instead of Europe/London)

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$Date = "2012-06-18T11:45:00Z";
$Date = str_replace("T"," ",$Date);
$Date = str_replace("Z"," ",$Date);
$FinalDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$Date"));
$FinalDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $FinalDate);
var_dump($FinalDate);
?>
```

var_dump outputs:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2012-06-18 11:45:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/London"
}
```